# Any examples of how to write an application that is executable from the terminal like git?

Tags: gnome, python

I want to write an Ubuntu application that helps me deal with a web-based API. I can write it in Python, but I want to know how to build it so that I can execute it as a command on the terminal itself.

Comment: This isn't specific to Ubuntu. You may be better off asking programming questions on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 7):

Put your Python program in a text file. The first line of that file should be

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

 print "Hello world"
```

(I put the "Hello world" line just as an example of Python code). Save it as a text file, for example `test.py`. Make that file executable

```
 chmod a+x test.py
```

Presto, you can now run it:

```
 ./test.py
```

To be able to access it from any directory and for every user, put it in `/usr/local/bin`, which is the default location for executables not installed with package managers:

```
sudo cp test.py /usr/local/bin
```

Alternatively, you can make a directory called "bin" in your home directory; it will be automatically appended to your PATH variable from through the $HOME/.profile file.

```
mkdir $HOME/bin
mv test.py $HOME/bin
```

In both of these two last cases to run your script in the terminal, you have to write only:

```
test.py
```

The extension ".py" is here only for you to indicate that it is a Python script. You can call it "susan" and run it by typing

```
susan
```

It will work the same.

Comment: Thank you but I know that. I wanted to know how to make it executable like this: typing "test" on the terminal should print me hello world.

Comment: Huh, you can call it "test" or "susan" for what I care :-) In Linux, extensions are for your eyes only -- the system doesn't really care about them. Rename it to "test", move it to a folder from your PATH like /usr/local/bin or /home/user/bin and bob is your uncle. (but beware: there already is a program called "test")

Answer (score 2):

Python is a scripting language, which means that you don't have to compile it before running. All you need is getting required version of Python interpreter installed.

For example, you have a python script named foo.py in your home directory, you can run that script with command

```
$ ~/foo.py
```

The first line in the file should tell it's a python file. First line should be like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Assuming it's set as executable, if not:

```
$ chmod +x ~/foo.py
```

If what you want is to run it without any `~/` stuff, you should move it to your $PATH.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

If you move foo.py in `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/bin` or `/bin` you can run without any parent folder.

```
$ sudo mv ~/foo.py /usr/local/bin
$ foo.py
```

Comment: This will not work unless you specify the interpreter in the Python file. This first line, '#!/usr/bin/python' is by no means required by the Python language, so if it is missing, `python test.py` will work, but `./test.py` not.

Answer (score 1):

As it works fine to put a small python script to `/usr/local/bin` to be able to run it from the command line (see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/187640/3940)) we may have a more elaborate python application that we need to store in another place (e.g in `/opt/myapp/`).

We can then write a small script we put in `/usr/local/bin/` that references to our python script like e.g.

```
#! /bin/bash

python /opt/myapp/myapp.py "$@"
```

Add the variable `"$@"` in case your script take command line parameters.

Comment: Edited your message so it now correctly reads `#!`. Other than that, what's the point of calling bash to call python when you can directly call python?